# How to limit the width of a Button in NativeScript?

Tags: css, nativescript

I'm using NativeScript-Vue to build some app. Trying to figure out how to control the size of my buttons. For instance, i have this code:

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
              <Button
                class="fas"
                :text="'fa-upload' | fonticon"
                @tap="()=>{backupImage(image)}"
              ></Button>
              <Button

                v-if="image.taskStatus==='pending'"
                class="far"
                :text="'fa-window-close' | fonticon"
                @tap="()=>{cancelImageBackup(image)}"
              ></Button>
  </StackLayout>
```

The result is this:
[image]

I would like to **remove the large "empty" gray area, on both sides of the icon.** I see that native script doesn't support max-width. Tried also padding. How can it be done?

Comment: Try adding custom CSS classes to icon button and give `width: 60px !important` in your project stylesheet.

Comment: If this doesn't work please provide a stackblitz demo.

Comment: FYI, as of today `!important` is not supported by {N}. Try avoid `px` unit (the default unit system will be DPI), unless you are trying to restrict the size across different screen densities.

Comment: Yes, i see it works also without the !important, so i basically just had to use the "width" property...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, works with a StackLayout around it

```html
<StackLayout>
  <Button text="LOGIN" class="-rounded-sm bg-primary" width="100dip"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```